# Is there a way to validate the WooCommerce auction function automatically after a customer orders a specific product pack?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Good morning,

I am trying to modify a value of a fields in our shop customers account dokan with woocommerce auctions simple like module after it is made a purchase of a specific product.

That is to say that the woocommerce auction system is installed and is by default deactivated for all accounts created.

After he buys an auction pack product I want to deactivate the function set up so that he can use the auction module.

my goal is when a customer orders a product pack called auction after the order, we automatically validate the auction function so he can use the auction.

Thanks for your help

I found this function in the auction module:

```
     /** * Disable selling capability by default once a seller is registered * * @since 1.0.0 * * @param int $user_id */ public function dokan_admin_user_register_enable_auction( $user_id ) { $user = new WP_User( $user_id ); $role = reset( $user->roles );
    
            if ( 'seller' === (string) $role ) {
                if ( 'off' === (string) dokan_get_option( 'new_seller_enable_auction', 'dokan_selling' ) ) {
                    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'dokan_disable_auction', 'yes' );
                } else {
                    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'dokan_disable_auction', 'no' );
                }
            }
        }
```

in my functions.php page of the child theme I added this but it does not work.

```
function enchere_activer( $order_id ) {

$order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
$items = $order->get_items();

foreach ( $items as $item ) {
   $product_id = $item['product_id'];
}

if ( $order->user_id > 0 && $product_id == '8477' ) {
    
    $user_id = new WP_User( $order->user_id );
    
   update_user_meta( $user_id, 'dokan_disable_auction', 'no' );

   
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed', 'enchere_activer' );
```

my goal is when a customer orders a product pack called auction after the order validates automatically he can use the auction.

Here is the code on the user account with the checkbox that should be automatically deactivated after ordering.

```
 <th>Annonces format enchère</th>
            <td>
                <label for="dokan_disable_auction">
                    <input type="hidden" name="dokan_disable_auction" value="no">
                    <input name="dokan_disable_auction" type="checkbox" id="dokan_disable_auction" value="yes"  checked='checked' />
                    Désactiver l'enchère                </label>

                <p class="description">Désactiver la capacité de vendre aux enchères pour ce vendeur</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        
                <input type="hidden" id="dokan_update_user_profile_info_nonce" name="dokan_update_user_profile_info_nonce" value="8206b9f685" /><input type="hidden" name="_wp_http_referer" value="/wp-admin/user-edit.php?user_id=8&wp_http_referer=%2Fwp-admin%2Fusers.php" />            </tbody>
        </table>
```

thank you